# jqGrid onclick row new table

Tags: jquery, jsp, jqgrid

I am new to jqGrid and managed to experiment with the basic grid features.
My current scenario requires to display some data from a DB in the grid.
The onclick event on the row should update the grid with a new set of data obtained from the DB.

Something along the line of a list of employees, the onclick makes the employee ID obtain the details of that employee and updates.
I don't want to use a subgrid. I would like to update the main grid instead, with a provision of a link to navigate to the main grid.
Not sure how to proceed with the idea.

**Option 2: -** 
If I maintain 2 grid, when the page loads for the first time, I want some details in grid A, If I select one row I should get the details of that row from DB to the Grid B where grid A should be hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a master/detail example in the [jqGrid demos](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) under `Advanced` | `Master Detail` that demonstrates how to load data into a second (Detail) grid when selecting a row in the first (Master) grid.

You could use this approach in your application to avoid having to use a subgrid.